# Facebook Login Button Text

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am implementing the Facebook Login with my app.
I can set the text of a Facebook login button through the .xml file.

Like This

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Custom Text Here"/>
```

I have seen questions that answer how to set text through the xml file, but is there anyway to do it programatically?

Edit The reason I want to do it programatically is because I'm using a `SpannableStringBuilder` that is using FontAwesome icons.

Like so:

```
SpannableStringBuilder facebook = new SpannableStringBuilder(getString(R.string.fa_icon_facebook) + " Facebook");
        facebook.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", fontAwesome, this), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        facebook.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", champagneRegularFont, this), 1, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this ?

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString("Facebook Login");
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);     
// some other customizations...

loginButton.setText(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - at least from what I can tell Facebook handles a lot of that magic behind the scenes. The solution is a programmatic login from any button style you like.